# How to justify the text in Figure caption in Bootstrap 5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to justify the text in Figure caption Bootstrap 5.
As an example:

```
<figure class="figure">
  <img class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" src="fig.png" alt="" />
  <figcaption class="figure-caption text-start">my caption... long text...</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Here I use `text-start` to align left. I want something like `text-justify` but it doesn't work. How can I justify the text?

Answer (score 1):

It is kind of strange and I did have to go have a look but on appearances Bootstrap does not have a class for justifying text. It would seem the best option is to use `class="text-wrap"` and I suppose this may work better or worse if you also include `text-center`.

Alternatively, you could justify the text manually in your CSS using `text-align: justify;`

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed, the solution is

```
<figure class="figure">
  <img class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" src="fig.png" alt="" />
  <figcaption class="figure-caption">my caption... long text...</figcaption>
</figure>
```

and in css:

```
.figure-caption {display: table-caption; caption-side: bottom; text-align: justify;}
```